# Can't call ec2.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressInput when using other than the default VPC (aws-sdk-go)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2

When running the below code, I get the error message

```
InvalidGroup.NotFound The security group 'OddName' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-2468'
```

That is the correct VPC name, but not the VPC ID that would be seen when looking at sg-1357.  This is a request error, not an aws error, so it's getting at least that far.

From the command line this works:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-1357 --cidr 127.0.0.1/32  --protocol tcp --port 443
```

And I can confirm the ip has been added.

Modifying the example code from the [sdk on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/ec2/examples_test.go), the following produces the default VPC error:

```
func ExampleEC2_AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress() {
svc := ec2.New(nil)

params := &ec2.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressInput{
    CIDRIP:    aws.String("127.0.0.1"),
    DryRun:    aws.Boolean(true),
    FromPort:  aws.Long(443),
    GroupID:   aws.String("sg-1357"),
    GroupName: aws.String("OddName"),
    IPPermissions: []*ec2.IPPermission{
        { // Required
            FromPort:   aws.Long(1),
            IPProtocol: aws.String("String"),
            IPRanges: []*ec2.IPRange{
                { // Required
                    CIDRIP: aws.String("String"),
                },
                // More values...
            },
            PrefixListIDs: []*ec2.PrefixListID{
                { // Required
                    PrefixListID: aws.String("String"),
                },
                // More values...
            },
            ToPort: aws.Long(1),
            UserIDGroupPairs: []*ec2.UserIDGroupPair{
                { // Required
                    GroupID:   aws.String("String"),
                    GroupName: aws.String("String"),
                    UserID:    aws.String("String"),
                },
                // More values...
            },
        },
        // More values...
    },
    IPProtocol:                 aws.String("String"),
    SourceSecurityGroupName:    aws.String("String"),
    SourceSecurityGroupOwnerID: aws.String("String"),
    ToPort: aws.Long(443),
}
resp, err := svc.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress(params)

if err != nil {
    if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        // Generic AWS error with Code, Message, and original error (if any)
        fmt.Println(awsErr.Code(), awsErr.Message(), awsErr.OrigErr())
        if reqErr, ok := err.(awserr.RequestFailure); ok {
            // A service error occurred
            // ERROR GETS REPORTED HERE
            fmt.Println(reqErr.Code(), reqErr.Message(), reqErr.StatusCode(), reqErr.RequestID())
        }
    } else {
        // This case should never be hit, the SDK should always return an
        // error which satisfies the awserr.Error interface.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}

// Pretty-print the response data.
fmt.Println(awsutil.StringValue(resp))
```

}

Comment: Have you tried some variations on the inputs? Just noticing minor differences between the bash command and the string literals in Go for example; `sg-1357` vs `1357`. A glance at the docs makes me think you need the former.

Comment: I do have the correct GroupID in my actual code.  That was an error when deleting my specific data.  Edited the code to reflect sg-1357

Comment: I'm getting nit picky but your `CIDRIP` value is also a little different. Also, can you just remove the groupName from the command? It says it's looking in the default VPC for that group however your use of an GroupID indicates you might be using something other than the default? Besides that neither are required so I would think one of the two would suffice.

Comment: I nearly answered that I had tried removing the GroupName. So the answer would be "Comment out the GroupName: line" and it works up to the DryRun error.  If you answer I'll confirm it.  Thanks.

Comment: my pleasure and much appreciate the opportunity to answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you comment out the `GroupName` line it will work up to the `DryRun` error.

params end up looking like this:

```
  params := &ec2.AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressInput{
    CIDRIP:    aws.String("127.0.0.1/32"),
    DryRun:    aws.Boolean(true),
    FromPort:  aws.Long(443),
    GroupID:   aws.String("sg-1357"),
    IPProtocol:                 aws.String("tcp"),
    SourceSecurityGroupName:    aws.String(""),
    SourceSecurityGroupOwnerID: aws.String(""),
    ToPort: aws.Long(443),
  }
```